# JPA repository method same or different

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring boot app, which has 'User' entity and 'UserRepository' class. When I was writing JPA methods I saw that we can write two methods as

```
List <User> findUsersByName(String name);
List <User> findByName(String name);
```

Which returns the same result set(as I saw). Is there any difference between these two JPA methods?

Comment: i think best comparison would be to check the log console when calling these methods and inspect both sql queries.

Comment: There is no difference as they use similar SQL request to the database, you can re-check it in logs by enabling sql logging. `findById` method name be more clear in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

As [*Simon Martinelli*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66781632/66686) noted correctly you should be careful with redefining `findById` since it already exists and has a [custom implementation, which can be found on Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/1b7f5c46e8bd4160794071aed0e5a4c5ec661c7a/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L295).

But in similar cases where the does not exist a custom implementation, say

```
List <User> findUsersByName(String name);
List <User> findByName(String name);
```

both variants are identical.
With query derivation almost everything between `find` and `By` is ignored and can for example be used to distinguish methods that perform the same basic query but use different [entity graphs](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs).

Comment: actually, I was using the id field as an example, in the actual scenario, I have used the method for different attribute as you described in your answer, sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 2):

Don't use findById because this is already defined on the CrudRepository and is used to find one or no result (Optional).

```
/**
 * Retrieves an entity by its id.
 *
 * @param id must not be {@literal null}.
 * @return the entity with the given id or {@literal Optional#empty()} if none found.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@literal id} is {@literal null}.
 */
Optional<T> findById(ID id);
```

Comment: yes, thanks for mentioning, actually I was using the id field as an example, in actual synario, I have used the method for different attribute, sorry for the misunderstanding